# How to use Primary Scroll controller in sub tree in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Future<void> main() async {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
          await configureDependencies();
        
          runApp(const MyApp());
        }
        
        class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
          const MyApp({super.key});
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => getIt<LocationControllBloc>(),
              child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter Demo',
                theme: ThemeData(
                  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
                  useMaterial3: true,
                ),
                home: MyTestingPage(),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

    class MyTestingPage extends StatelessWidget {
              MyTestingPage({super.key});
              final controller = ScrollController();
            
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: PrimaryScrollController(
                      controller: controller,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        primary: true,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Center(child: SmartProgressButton()),
                            ChildWidget(),
                            Placeholder(
                              fallbackHeight: 2000,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            };
    
    //Nexted widget in another file
     
    class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          const ChildWidget({super.key});
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      try {
                        final controller = 
     PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Check'))
              ],
            );
          }
```

I am try to access the contoller from child got an error: "Exception has occurred. FlutterError (PrimaryScrollController.of() was called with a context that does not contain a PrimaryScrollController widget. No PrimaryScrollController widget ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to PrimaryScrollController.of(). This can happen because you are using a widget that looks for a PrimaryScrollController ancestor, but no such ancestor exists. The context used was:   ChildWidget(dependencies: [PrimaryScrollController])) !D/EGL_emulation

Comment: Can you more snippet that will reproduce the same error, try to include from MaterialApp.

Comment: Added full details